# Grouping by date and time, with certain layout

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of dates, every date has several timestamps, and every time stamp has a value. 
I have to rearange this data in a specific way. here's the data and below the way it should be arranged

7/07/2014   03:55   69
6/07/2014   22:49   91
6/07/2014   17:13   143
6/07/2014   10:29   75
6/07/2014   00:50   149
5/07/2014   22:37   97
5/07/2014   19:40   152
5/07/2014   13:12   101
5/07/2014   09:32   98

I need to group these in a certain way

07/07/2014  03:55
    .......................69

06/07/2014  00:50   10:29   17:13   22:49
.....................   149 . .. 75...  143.....    91

05/07/2014  09:32   13:12   19:40   22:37
    ........................98  ....101..   153.....    97

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by formatting the dates as text, adding a helper column, then pulling it into a pivot table.  See below.

I think your dates and times are split in your original post.  If so, just format your dates as text.

The solution below assumes the sort order shown in your original data.

Add a helper column, which below is labeled "ctDate".  That column counts occurences of the dates.  Note carefully the placement of the dollar signs in the formula.

Pivot the data in a classic pivot table layout as shown.  Once it's pivoted, you'll want to Select the "Sum of Time" value, insure it is a "sum", and then give it a custom format of "hh:mm"

If you then need to get rid of the headings in the pivot table's "Values" column, you can do one of two things:
 1. Copy/paste special/values and formats to a different location, then strip out what you don't need.  or....
 2. In the "Value Field Settings" dialog box shown below, you could enter " " for the Custom Name.

Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: There is a typo I believe in the formula for cell D2,

Comment: For some reason when I select all 4 colums and choose pivot table, it doesn't bring the colomn ctDate into the table, it's not in the 
"choose field to add to report" list.

Also, here is a typo I believe in the formula for cell D2. 
The last B10 should be B2.

Comment: Issue resolved.
appaerently there was a problem with the amount of data.
Thank You

Comment: You're correct about the typo --- apologies!  

Otherwise....is it a solution to your issue?

Comment: Yes this is a good solution. Thank you for your help.